# PHP fread reading the string '0'

Tags: php, fread

hello i use fread like this to get an integer from an url:

```
$f = fopen("http://sometextfilecontaininganinteger.txt", "r");
$incoming = fread($f, 16);
fclose($f);
if ($incoming)
{
```

the if check is there to see if the http call was successful.
unfortunately this fails also when the textfile contains the string '0'.
how could i work around this?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

Comment: also check http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php for other methods for reading remote files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
if ($incoming)
{
```

you have to use

```
if ($incoming !== FALSE)
{
```

Because '0' equals to FALSE when not comparing the type.

Answer (score 2):

Check if it is "[Not identical](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)"

```
if ($incoming !== false) {
   // ...
}
```